# Visual Studio 2015, missing library System.Xml.Linq

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, linq, linq-to-xml

Sorry for the noob-sounding question, but I'm doing a project for school where I need to query some data from an XML file, a format that i have exactly zero experience with so I'm not sure I'm doing it right.

After checking out a bunch of different languages, I decided that the C# library LINQ to XML looks like the easiest, syntactically speaking, to work with so I'm gonna roll with it.  I've never really worked in C# before but I have a ton of experience in Java, C, and C++ so I'm confident I can pick it up quickly.

It was my understanding that the library already came with C# when I downloaded the language when I first installed Visual Studio (Which I have never worked with before this class I'm in now so I'm not sure 100% how it works.)

After checking out a tutorial, I was alerted that I could utilize the library by including `using System.Xml.Linq`.  However, when I tried the basic command `XDocument xmlDocument = new XDocument()`, I got an error that "XDocument" could not be found, and another error that `Linq` doesn't exist within the `System.Xml` namespace.

I'm really stuck because it's pretty much the consensus that our professor isn't very good and I've asked around but nobody in the class really knows what to do so asking my peers hasn't been any help.

Thanks for your patience and any available help you guys can give me.

Comment: are you using framework 3.5 (or higher)?  (go to project->properties). Have you explicitly added a reference to  System.Xml.Linq  ?

Comment: try to check your reference. make sure `System.Xml` and `System.Xml.Linq` is there.

Comment: @MitchWheat If I looked in the right spot, it appears that I'm using .NET framework 4.6. does that sound correct?

Comment: @active92 -- `System.Xml` is there and I get no errors when I include that, as well as `System.Linq` if it makes any difference.  but `System.Xml.Linq` does not work.

Comment: @EthanFox Your framework is fine. You need to add `System.Xml.Linq` as a reference as well before you can call it at the namespace.

Comment: @active92 whenever I type `using System.Xml.Linq`, the `Linq` part gets underlined red and Visual Studio says it doesn't exist.  It also suggests that I might be missing an 'assembly reference' but I'm not sure what that means.  `System.Xml;` works fine on it's own and does not give me an error so it appears the be the `Linq` part that gives me an issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to project references and add a reference to  `System.Xml.Linq` :

[image]

[How to: Add or Remove References By Using the Add Reference Dialog Box](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx)

Comment: Thank you very much!  I was not aware that to work with certain libraries i needed to add them to my references.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I think you are confused.

`System.Xml` and `System.Xml.Linq` are two different references.

You will have to add `System.Xml.Linq`, then call `using System.Xml.Linq` in your namespace.

Answer (score 1):

Click add reference and browse at location 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.6\System.Xml.Linq.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.6\System.Xml.dll